# Fallback if .clientHeight is null and there is no element

Tags: jquery, canvas

I have 2 canvas elements on a website. The javascript checks for the height and the wide of a surrounding div and set the canvas height and width like it.

`var height = parseInt(document.getElementById("canvaselement").clientHeight);
 var height2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("canvaselement2").clientHeight);`

The problem is that if the one of the two canvas elements doesnt exist on a subpage, the script stops working.

The console gives me `**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'clientHeight' of null **`

I tried it with something like

```
if (height = null) {
    console.log("height null");
}
```

How can i get a fallback if a canvas element is not present? Any ideas or suggestion?

regards
denym

Comment: The error explains you that the element that you trying to get height from is null. Not the height itself. So you should check the following: 

`document.getElementById("canvaselement") == null`

Comment: Also, check if the element exists before you are trying to get any properties of it.

Comment: @Hless is correct...check your html for a missing/wrongly-id'ed canvas element.  If you actually do need to create a new canvas in javascript, you can do it like this:  var newCanvas=document.createElement("canvas").  After setting your desired attributes on newCanvas, you can then use someElement.addChild(newCanvas) to add your newly created canvas to the DOM.

Comment: This property is read-only.
Note that the clientHeight property does not work for HTML elements whose display type is inline. There are several HTML elements (inline HTML elements), whose display type is inline by default (such as: a, span, b, img etc.). If you need to use the clientHeight property of an inline HTML element, set its display style property to 'block'.Read more here: http://help.dottoro.com/ljcadejj.php